# Please make sure to create a Relative Folder Path within the EnhancedFTP root

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

I am attempting to create a File Location that is a directory in which I will be dropping off a data extension extract. I have selected the following settings:

> Name: File_Location_Name
>
> Location Type: Relative location under FTP Site
>
> Relative Folder Path : Import/[folder_name]/[folder_name]/[folder_name]

When attempting to save this File Location. I get the following error message:

> Please fix the following errors :
> Please make sure to create a Relative Folder Path within the EnhancedFTP root.

The folder location I am referencing does in fact exist and I am looking at it in FileZilla. Is anyone aware as to why I am getting this error?

Comment: Have you verified it is not the FTP from a different BU that you are looking at?

Comment: @Gortonington I have verified that it is not the FTP from a different BU

Comment: My best advice then if you are 100% certain your path matches the path you see in filezilla, then I would push a support ticket as I am unable to replicate your issue. Also, to fit the format that SFMC uses, I would use the backslash ('\') not slash ('/') in your path. I believe both will be accepted, but as they state this is the correct format, it may help reduce possible issues down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP user defined at the parent level had proper privileges for sub folder access. When creating a new account under a specific business unit, the privileges were not mirrored therefore could not access sub folders. Solution was to disable the account. The disabled account must be pushed by the Salesforce Support team, it won't work by just disabling account yourself.